# Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null - WordPress / Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, console, contact-form-7

Seem to be getting an error on our contact forms on version 5.4.1 and the version before using the Contact Form 7 plugin on WordPress. The error occurs when submitting the form regardless of entering information or not. The error which appears in console is as follows:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
at c (index.js?ver=5.4.1:1)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at index.js?ver=5.4.1:1
```

Read a couple of articles about rolling back to version 5.3.2 which I can confirm works and the issue isn't present in this version. Does anyone have a fix for it though? Or do we need to wait for another update? It's been a couple of weeks now since this was first found I believe.

If anyone needs any other information please let me know and I'll try to supply it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit

```
define( ‘WPCF7_LOAD_JS’, true );
```

to

```
define( ‘WPCF7_LOAD_JS’, false );
```

on wp-contact-form-7.php file.

Comment: Hi there, this works. However now that CF7 isn't loading the JS when I click submit/send it now reloads the page instead of using the nice Ajax way which looks cleaner to the user. Is there a solution which does both?

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a incompatability between your theme or a plugin with the new version of jquery used in wordpress. There are a few things you can do.

- Update your theme and plugins and hope the JavaScript is patched by the author
- Try to patch the broken code your self (this requires knowledge of javascript)
- Install [jQueryMigrate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-jquery-migrate-helper/) Plugin (this is only a Band-Aid and should not be the permanent solution)